# DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException occurred

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnetopenauth, google-oauth

I created an asp.net MVC 4 Internet application and enabled Google authentication.

after successful login, always 'IsSuccessful' property value is false in OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication method.

**it is working fine when I run the same solution in an another machine.**

I also turned off my firewall and tried, no luck.

I traced and found that some exception occurred in OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication method.

Here is the exception detail:

```
DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging.ProtocolException occurred  
HResult=-2146233088
Message=Web request to 'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/ud' failed.
Source=DotNetOpenAuth.Core

Inner Exception: 
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

I would really appreciate any help.